# creating route on MapView

Tags: iphone, xcode, mkmapview

I am working on small assignment.This is MKMapView based project, in which i am  drawing a route  from user's current location. I have already got the user's city by reversegeocoding .I am using textField for entering the desire destination.I was using  github.com/Surya121/SBMapWithRoute this sample project but this project is very complex. I could not implement it  on my project.This made me very frustrated. It would really very helpful if anybody guide me a more simple way to draw a route on Map. I shall be very thankful to you for this.

Comment: check this [Tutorial](http://iosguy.com/2012/05/22/tracing-routes-with-mapkit/)

Answer (score 1):

A [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial) from Ray Wenderlich's site might aid you.